# Wordpress site not working after password change via phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

I forgot my Wordpress site admin password,so  I have changed it via PhpMyAdmin using MD5 encryption, after that on my first login attempt it gave me database error and since then site pages are not loading at all.

Comment: Not really a programming question...

Comment: What password did you change? You mean admin password?

Comment: it was Admin password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official WordPress Codex has some good options for you:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Answer (score 0):

I think if wordpress is not using a MD5 encryption for the password.

you can try with [this site](http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php) make a new hash encryption password for your wordpress site.

Comment: This worked for me after trying even extremely simple password that was md5 hashed.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this site](http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/) and input your password which you wish to put then create md5 password ,copy and paste it to table through phpmyadmin